# initializate template object

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a little question...
I have this template class, it make a bidimensional array:

```
template <typename T, unsigned P>

class mapa {
private:
    T **mat;
    unsigned tam;

public:
    mapa(T &dato);
    mapa(const mapa& orig);
    virtual ~mapa();
    mapa<T, P> &operator=(const mapa<T, P> &orig);
    T &operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j);
};

template <class T, unsigned P>
mapa<T, P>::mapa(T &dato) {
    tam = P;
    mat = new T**[tam];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < P; i++) {
        mat[i] = new T*[tam];
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < P; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = dato;
        }
    }
}

template <class T, unsigned P>
mapa<T, P>::~mapa() {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        delete mat[i];
    }
    delete mat;
}

template <typename T, unsigned P>
T &mapa<T, P>::operator ()(unsigned i, unsigned j) {
    /*if (i < 0 || i >= tam) {
        throw ErrordeRango("Posición de memoria inexistente.");
    }
    if (j < 0 || j >= tam) {
        throw ErrordeRango("Posición de memoria inexistente.");
    }
    if (k < 0 || k >= tam) {
        throw ErrordeRango("Posición de memoria inexistente.");
    }
    return mat[i][j][k];*/

}

template <typename T, unsigned P>
mapa<T, P> &mapa<T, P>::operator=(const mapa<T, P> &orig) {

    tam = orig.tam;
    mat = new T**[tam];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < P; i++) {
        mat[i] = new T*[tam];
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < P; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = orig[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
```

I want to use it in the next class:

```
class museo
{
    int sizeStep;
    mapa<objetoMuseo*, 50> mapaMuseo;

public:
    museo();
    ~museo();

    void visualizar();
};
```

How I should make the constructor in museo.cpp to initializate template object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize your fields using the initialization lists.

```
museo::museo()
: sizeStep(0), 
  mapaMuseo(???)
{
}
```

where of course between the ??? you should add a reference to an objectoMuseo pointer as that is what the constructor calls for.

Comment: Sorry, I'm here again. I'm doing that

 objetoMuseo *vacio = NULL;
mapaMuseo = new mapa(vacio);

But it is wrong =S

Comment: Please post the full code example to describe what you are trying to do, and what doesn't work? Troubles with compiling / unexpected behaviour?

Comment: I fix it! the problem was here:
mapaMuseo = new mapa(vacio);
And it should be:
mapaMuseo = new mapa<objetoMuseo*,50>(vacio);
Thanks a lot!!